# Using existential quantifier to express "There is a $P$ that is $Q$"

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

The textbook says that to express "There is a $P$ that is $Q$", one can write the following preposition:

$$ \exists x [P(x) \land Q(x)\ ] $$

However, I am unsure why I can't write like this:

$$ \exists x [P(x) \rightarrow Q(x)] $$

For the case of universial quantifier, I have the opposite question. The textbook says "All  $P$ is $Q$" can be written as below:

$$ \forall x [P(x) \rightarrow Q(x)] $$

and I am unsure why I can't write like this:

$$ \forall x [P(x) \land Q(x)] $$

I do understand that $P \land Q$ and $P \rightarrow Q$ are different in that $P \rightarrow Q$ also accepts vacuously true. But I am curious why $\forall$ can  accept vacously true while $\exists$ cannot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first $\exists x [P(x) \rightarrow Q(x)]$ is true if there is some $x$ for which $P(x)$ is false.  It is still true if $P(x)$ is always false.  Then there is not a $P$, so there cannot be a $P$ that is $Q$.  Similarly for the second $\forall x [P(x) \land Q(x)]$ requires that $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ are true for all $x$.  You only want to require $Q(x)$ when $P(x)$ is true.  If our universe is all naturals and $P(x)$ is $x=1$ while $Q(x)$ is $x \lt 10$ it is true that all $P$ are $Q$, but your translation is false because $x$ could be $11$